# Python3 from shell script from cron ubuntu 16.04

Tags: bash, python-3.x, cron

I have a Python3 program that I need to execute 2 minutes past every hour.

Unable to get python to execute directly from cron, I’ve written a shell script with the commands in it.

The crontab to execute this shell script is this:

```
*/2 * * * * bash /home/john/PYTHONS/MASTER.sh
```

The shell script is simple. I’ve tried various versions, including this:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/john/PYTHONS/
python3 ~/PYTHONS/COMPLEXPYTHON.py
python3 ~/PYTHONS/SIMPLEPYTHON.py
```

and including this:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/john/PYTHONS/GDAXDEV/VPUMP
python3 $HOME/PYTHONS/COMPLEXPYTHON.py
python3 $HOME/PYTHONS/SIMPLEPYTHON.py
```

Here’s the issue:

1. If I execute the shell script from the command line BOTH python scripts run just fine.
2. If I execute the shell script from cron, ONLY THE SECOND python script runs. The first one just doesn’t run at all. And, I can’t seem to find out why, or how to fix it.

Any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you are running from different directories in each case, this might be the issue.

Comment: What does `which python` give you? Do you activate some sort of python environment (virtualenv, conda etc) to run your scripts? Also, please don't run shell scripts with `bash <scriptname>` instead, make the script executable with `chmod +x` and just run it directly. I would also get rid of `~` and `$HOME` in the shell script and use the full path.

Comment: Thank you Emmet for the tips on shell usage. As a linux newbie this sort of stuff is so helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I see questions about this issue all around, and no single one of them solved the issue for me. Several hours of testing every combination of variables lead me to a solution that’s reliable.

I’m no longer using a shell script, but invoking python directly in cron.

First, we did this:

```
$ which python3
/home/john/[path to python]/bin/python3
```

So, we added the shebang in every one of the python files in the project:

```
#!/home/john/[path to python]/bin/python3
```

And, in cron we used the full path to that python3, as well as the full path to the WORKING.py file we wanted to run. We want the thing to run 5 minutes past every hour so:

```
5 * * * * /home/john/[path to python]/bin/python3 /home/john/[path to dir]/WORKING.py
```

However, the log files this produced were being placed in /home/john/, and I wanted them in the specific directory. Also, there are a load of additional python files in there – with the same names as python files in nearby directories – so I wanted to be certain that any call gets the right one.

So, I added a CD command at the beginning of the cron command:

```
5 * * * * cd /home/john/[path to dir]/ && /home/john/[path to python]/bin/python3 /home/john/path to dir]/WORKING.py
```

It’s been running reliably ever since.

I’m grateful for the resources at stackoverflow and the great and fast help I’ve received in this community, and I hope this entry helps save someone else a whole afternoon of frustration.